# Topic is MarkedForDeletion , how to force topic deletion without topic aggressive removal from disk and from zookeeper

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

We have kafka broker cluster version - 2.7 , we have 3 brokers machines

We removed the following topic , by following cli

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper zoo01:2181 --topic my_first_car
```

After 1 day

we still see the topics on kafka disk , and also from following command

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo01:2181 --describe 
Topic: my_first_car   PartitionCount: 200     ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.bytes=7434770380    MarkedForDeletion: true
        Topic: my_first_car   Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001       MarkedForDeletion: true
        Topic: my_first_car   Partition: 1    Leader: none    Replicas: 1002  Isr: 1002       MarkedForDeletion: true
        Topic: my_first_car   Partition: 2    Leader: none    Replicas: 1003  Isr: 1003       MarkedForDeletion: true
        Topic: my_first_car   Partition: 3    Leader: none    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001       MarkedForDeletion: true
        Topic: my_first_car   Partition: 4    Leader: none    Replicas: 1002  Isr: 1002       MarkedForDeletion: true
        Topic: my_first_car   Partition: 5    Leader: none    Replicas: 1003  Isr: 1003       MarkedForDeletion: true
        Topic: my_first_car   Partition: 6    Leader: none    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001       MarkedForDeletion: true
        Topic: my_first_car   Partition: 7    Leader: none    Replicas: 1002  Isr: 1002       MarkedForDeletion: true
```

We also notice that topics is exist on zookeeper under  `/topics`

So in order to try to complete delete this topic we restart all Kafka broker machines , but this isn't help

What are the next steps to delete the topic - `my_first_car`

It is ridiculous , that Kafka provide cli to delete topic , but actually topic stay on Kafka disk

Note - the last thing that we want is to delete the topic from the disks and from the zookeeper , but this is the ugly way

Comment: As mentioned before, please stick with `--bootstrap-server` not `--zookeeper`. This will not resolve the issue, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be `Leader: none`. Not sure how the ISR list is updated with valid values, but there seems to be some corruption between Zookeeper and the Controller node such that the Leader is unknown, so the topic data cannot be resolved in order to be deleted.

Comment: so the kafka cli can delete topics? , or this not for 100% ( I mean when kafka health is ok )

Comment: It can, but only for topics that have a leader assigned